# Conditional print on html of angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am looping through a list of products and then checking if the product Id is already present in an array of products(objects) , then printing the quantity else if the product is not in the object then trying to print 0. Below is the code I have tried till now.

```
<ion-item class="added" *ngFor="let item of fetchProducts();let key=index;">
  <ng-container  *ngFor="let cartitem of cart" >
     <span class="count" *ngIf="cartitem.p_id==item.p_id;">
         {{cartitem.qty}}
     </span>
   </ng-container>
</ion-item>
```

How to print 0 if `item` is not in the `cartitem` in same span.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply  do  this using ternary operator like below.

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let cartitem of cart" >
     <span class="count">
      {{cartitem.p_id==item.p_id ? cartitem.qty : 0 }}
     </span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: this will print 0 for every iteration of cart object

Comment: So you want only one zero if there is no item matches ? @AmarSingh

Comment: Working on it . Get back to you soon . @AmarSingh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using template logic I would move the logic to the class.

`cart` and `products` are obviously available in the class.
Therefore adjust the `fetchProducts` function in the class to return the products list as needed (with the quantity information) and use a single `ngFor` loop in the template.

Or add a new function `getProductsWithQuantity`...

In your class

```
    public getProductsWithQuantity() {
        return this.fetchProducts().map(product => {
            ...product,
            quantity: this.getQuantity(product);
        });
    }

    private getQuantity(product) {
        const foundCartItem = this.cart.find(cartItem => product.id === cartItem.id);
        if (foundCartItem) {
            return foundCartItem.qty;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

In your template:

```
<ion-item class="added" *ngFor="let item of getProductsWithQuantity();let key=index;">
   <span class="count">
       {{item.qty}}
   </span>
...
```

Comment: I tried this too . I created a function `getProdquantity` , and called in html page and passed the item object as argument in the iterations. It prints for the first time but does not update quantity value on the page when value is changed in cart object.

Comment: Do you you use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` ?

Comment: Nope did not used that. Could you elaborate.

Comment: your ngFor should look like this `<ion-item class="added" *ngFor="let item of getProductsWithQuantity();let key=index;">` And `getProductsWithQuantity` should return the list as needed (with the quantity information).

Comment: In that case I have to maintain another object other than Cart Object which will have  the list of all products with quanity. And I need to maintain this object whenever changes made to the cart object.

Comment: you do not have to introduce a new object. `getProductsWithQuantity()` will return a new array when it is called. the array is build based on the existing information from `cart` and `fetchProducts()`

Comment: Ok got it will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Can use *ngIf else condition inside your for loop -

```
<ion-item class="added" *ngFor="let item of fetchProducts();let key=index;">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let cartitem of cart">
    <span class="count" *ngIf="cartitem.p_id==item.p_id; then content else other_content">
    </span>
    <ng-template #content>{{cartitem.qty}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template #other_content>0</ng-template>

  </ng-container>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Your data will be outside span element and it will print 0 for every iteration of cart object.